# Signing an release-unsigned apk using keychain in os x

Tags: macos, ant, apk, release, keychain

I'm using jarsigner and zipalign to sign and align my release-unsigned apk I created using 'ant release.' I am using os x and created a certificate in the keychain to sign my apk but after I aligned and submitted my app, i got an error saying that my certificate expires too soon. How can i create a certificate that will expire at a date acceptable by Google Play using the the keychain utility in os x.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check `Let me override defaults` to select a defined `Validity Period (days)`:

[image: Self-Signed Cert]
[image: Override Default]